# Alternate of getSystemLoadAverage() for Windows?

Tags: java, cpu, cpu-usage, cpu-speed, mxbean

I am working on with some code to monitor Cpu load using Java. I am using following code in my app to get system load

```
public static double getCPULoad() {
    OperatingSystemMXBean osMBean
                = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

    double load = osMBean.getSystemLoadAverage();
    return load;
}
```

But on windows it returns me a negative value (-1.0). Is there any way i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read [this blog](https://www.java.net/community-item/hidden-java-7-features-%E2%80%93-system-and-process-cpu-load-monitoring).
It's not an official solution but when using `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` instead of `java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` there are two methods `getSystemCpuLoad()` and `getProcessCpuLoad()` that are working.

Comment: The "this blog" link is no longer available. Can somebody expand? How do we get the other one?

Comment: Ok, I got it to work by just calling com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean#getSystemCpuLoad.